# google spreadsheet calculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to calculate this:

```
0-10 hours = 100 pr. hour
11-20 hours = 80 pr. hour
21+   hours = 70 pr. hour


If ex. I have 23 hours:
10 hours - 100 pr. hour
10 hours -  80 pr. hour
 3 hours -  70 pr. hour
```

Is it possible to write a function in Google spreadsheet to calculate the total amount if I only have the total hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can express this as a formula. Consider that there are three cases:

1. If more than 20 hours, rate is (10 x 100 + 10 x 80) + (hours - 20) x 70
2. If less than 21 hours but more than 10, rate is (10 x 100) + (hours - 10) x 80
3. If less than 11 hours, rate is hours x 100

If we have our hours in cell `A1`, here's the formula:

```
=if(A1>20,(A1-20)*70+1800,if(A1>10,(A1-10)*80+1000,A1*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing gsheet formulas for 4+years.
IMHO you need to create additional table "rates"

HoursFrom | HoursTo | Rate

0         | 10      | 100

11        | 20      | 80

21        | 9999    | 70

than you can write flexible formula that will work everywhere:
= filter(rates!C:C, rates!A:A>A1, rates!B:B

it may seem a bit more complex in the beginning, but late you will easily read your formula and you will be able to change your data in single place in your "Rates" table without searching for all formulas that refer to this data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to write a function for this. Here is a sample code.

```
function amount(x) {
  if(!x){
    return "no hours provided";
  } else {
    if(x<=10){
      return x*100;
    } else if (x<=20){
      return 10*100+(x-10)*80;
    } else {
      return 10*100+10*80+(x-20)*70;
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this anywhere in the spreadsheet as a custom function. e.g. if

```
A1 = 23;
//You can put below line in any cell. A2 is just being given as an example
A2 = amount(A1) //answer will be 2010
```